# Text alignment in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

How can I align the column data to center in a WPF `DataGrid`?

Comment: For Silverlight, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916226/column-aligment-in-a-silverlight-datagrid/7916301#7916301).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing specifics, but here's a `DataGridTextColumn` that is centered:

```
<wpf:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <wpf:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </wpf:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</wpf:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Worked great for me even in Dec 2010!

Comment: This approach didn't work for me.  The text was centered, but the cell width no longer matched up with its header.  Mohammed's solution worked best.

Comment: As Kiff said, the cell is shifting too. You must target the Textblock like Mohammed A. Fadil exemple.

Answer (score 106):

If you are using DataGridTextColumn you can use the following code snippet:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
     </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is best way - setting alignment on the cell causes the cell not to fill its width, which looks odd when the row is selected

Comment: Initially this didn't work for me, but after a bit more testing and fixing some errors in my code this solution worked great.  thanks!

Comment: @BrianVPS Welcomes, I am happy to hear that :D

Comment: @Priyank Thakkar, Welcomes :D

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25507802/1563422) for a C# code-behind version of this.

Comment: For me this approach just center the text horizontally, but how to center it also vertically?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179080/536172) if you want to center only one column.

Answer (score 24):

I started with huttelihut's solution. Unfortunately, that didn't work for me just yet. I tweaked his answer and came up with this (solution is to align the text to the right):

```
<Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RightAligned" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</Resources>
```

As you can see, I applied the style to a TextBlock, not the DataGridCell.

And then I had to set the **Element** style, not the **Cell** style.

```
ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAligned}"
```

Comment: Please note that this does not work with the `DataGridTextColumn`

Comment: @JP Hellemons: for me it worked with `DataGridTextColumn`

Answer (score 15):

+1 for Kent Boogaart.
I ended up doing this, which makes the code slightly less cluttered (and enables me to use the alignment on several columns):

```
<Resources>
      <Style x:Key="NameCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      </Style>
</Resources>


<DataGrid.Columns>                           
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" CellStyle="{StaticResource NameCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>                            
    // .. other columns        
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: +1 for style, but for me `HorizontalAlignment` does not work whereas `HorizontalContentAlignment` does.

Comment: You can do the same with a DataGridColumnHeader style and set that as the HeaderStyle.  Nice clean solution.

Answer (score 9):

Here's @MohammedAFadil's XAML answer, converted to C# code behind:

```
var MyStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell)) {
    Setters = {
        new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center)
    }
};
```

To apply the `Style`, set the `CellStyle` property of the `DataGrid`, e.g.

```
var MyGrid = new DataGrid() {
    CellStyle = MyStyle
};
```

Comment: Simple and clean! +1 :) Just what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Or in code behind:

```
grid.CellStyle = newCellStyle();

public static Style newCellStyle()
{
    //And here is the C# code to achieve the above
    System.Windows.Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
    style.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
    {
        Property = Control.HorizontalAlignmentProperty,
        Value = HorizontalAlignment.Center
    });
    return style;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I ended up having problems with the cell being shifted and looking funky using the accepted answer. I know it's late, but hopefully my findings will help someone. I use:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
     <Style>
          <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     </Style>
```

rather than the CellStyle.

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still looking for answer for this, here's what worked for me:

```
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this one works well

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Balance, StringFormat=C} "Header="Balance">
  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment"  Value="Right"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I used the frameworkElement approach but there was a strange behavior when you try to highlight the row.

I've put another example of WPF Datagrid alignment in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050536/highlight-entire-rows-only-in-silverlight-datagrid/1324343#1324343)!

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution is:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="My Column" Binding="{Binding MyDBValue}" Width="100" >
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Danny Beckett for converting @MohammedAFadil's XAML answer, converted to C# code. All of my datagrids are set up dynamically, so I can change anything, whenever.

To set up an empty datagrid, with nothing in it and then just bind it to data, just take your datagrid.columns

```
        var centerTextSetter = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell))
        {
            Setters = { new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center) }
        };
        DgDbNames.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = "Db Name",
            Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("DbName"),
            IsReadOnly = true,
            Width = new DataGridLength(0.2, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star),
            CellStyle = centerTextSetter
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Bruno's TextBlock.TextAlignment approach. You can use this in conjunction with horizontal alignment and then any background will stretch across the whole grid cell.

e.g. (in VB)

```
    Dim sty = New System.Windows.Style(GetType(DataGridCell))
    sty.Setters.Add(New Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch))
    sty.Setters.Add(New Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right))
    sty.Setters.Add(New Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightGray))
```