# Align Header and Rows in a Styled DataGrid in SilverLight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid, styling, alignment

I have a Grid, which is displaying this odd behavior:

[image: My Headers totally oddly aligned]

Everytime I have horizontal scrollbars available, and I use it, the headers get disaligned with the cells of the rows.

My grid is styled this way:

```
 <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                    <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <vsm:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                </vsm:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"    />
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal AlternatingRow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".65"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#666666"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal Selected">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="5"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" 
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" 
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#ddddff"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                                       Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.FontWeight)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver Selected" >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="50" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="50" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#ccccff"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                                       Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.FontWeight)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>

                                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>



                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                                       Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.FontWeight)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>

                                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*">

                            </RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--<Grid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight" Duration="00:00:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Grid.Resources>-->

                        <Border x:Name="Borda"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"  ></Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Fill="#1ca0f2" >

                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" FontSize="12" >


                            <localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Name="CellsPresenter" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" >

                            </localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <localprimitives:DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="3" Name="RowHeader" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" />

                        <localprimitives:DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="DetailsPresenter" />
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="BottomGridLine" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" />
                    </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

For a while, if I take the customization off of the grid (the codeblock above) from my application it works, however, I loose some visual styles, which I don't want to.

I particularly don't understand WHAT in my stylization could make it happen, for I don't fully understand it. Would someone know?

Thanks in advance.

Regards!

Clayton Freitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by putting the template code **inside** the grid definition, not outside, like I was doing.

[Highlight entire rows only in Silverlight DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050536/highlight-entire-rows-only-in-silverlight-datagrid)