# Silverlight DataGrid column headers won't line up with data when style applied

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I have a Silverlight datagrid which has a RowStyle applied to highlight certain rows. There are more columns than can fit on a screen, so there is a horizontal scrollbar. However, when scrolling to the right, the data columns quickly get out of sync with the header.

I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848125/align-header-and-rows-in-a-styled-datagrid-in-silverlight) by moving the style definition directly into the datagrid code in the XAML, but that did not work for me. I know the style is causing the problem, but I can't determine what part is the culprit! I have provided the style and datagrid definitions below. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
<sdk:DataGrid MinHeight="100" Margin="0,0,0,30" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgResults" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FindResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    RowStyle="{StaticResource RowColorableDataGrid}" toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behavior:SelectRowOnRightClickBehavior />
                            <mybehavior:DepartureContextMenuBehavior/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="False" Header="Select">
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="True"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Path=Tourcode}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Tour" Binding="{Binding Path=TourDescription}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Binding="{Binding Path=Brand}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Land Start Date" Binding="{Binding Path=LandStartDate}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Land End Date" Binding="{Binding Path=LandEndDate}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="TIP Avail" Binding="{Binding Path=Availability}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="GSpace" Binding="{Binding Path=GSpace}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Per PAX (TWN)" Binding="{Binding Path=PricePerPaxTwin}" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Per PAX (SGL)" Binding="{Binding Path=PricePerPaxSingle, StringFormat='+0;-0;0'}" Width="Auto" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Per PAX (TPL)" Binding="{Binding Path=PricePerPaxTriple, StringFormat='+0;-0;0'}" Width="Auto" />
                        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Here is the RowStyle XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="data:DataGridRow" x:Key="RowColorableDataGrid">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="data:DataGridRow">
                    <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid x:Name="Root">
                        <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="DetailsVisibleTransition">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentHeight"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                        <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NormalAlternatingRow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NormalSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnfocusedSelected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="#FFE1E7EC"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="InvalidVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Fill="{Binding RowBackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="InvalidVisualElement" Fill="#FFF7D8DB" Opacity="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        <localprimitives:DataGridRowHeader x:Name="RowHeader" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Foreground="{Binding RowForegroundColor, Mode=OneWay}">
                            <localprimitives:DataGridCellsPresenter x:Name="CellsPresenter" localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <localprimitives:DataGridDetailsPresenter x:Name="DetailsPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BottomGridLine" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Any chance you might want to slap a quick screenshot up of what you're experiencing to help visualize the question without having to load a bunch of mock stuff to run your snippets? :)

Comment: Thanks for the response @ChrisW.! I did add a screenshot; unfortunately the site would not let me post it because I just created my account. So I just uploaded it to my website, and you can see it here:

http://www.jbrianmartinez.com/images/scroll_sync.png

In the example, the date should be under "Land Start Date", "OPN" should be under "Status" and so on. It looks like the last column blows out which pushes all of the data columns to the left and gets them out of sync with their headers.