# Column aligment in a Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: .net, silverlight, datagrid

How can you set the alignment of cell content in a Silverlight DataGrid?

The approach given for WPF DataGrids at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720732/column-aligment-in-wpf-datagrid) doesn't seem to work in Silverlight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#:

```
var rightCellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
rightCellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(
    Control.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty,
    HorizontalAlignment.Right));
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn {
    Binding = /* binding */,
    Header = /* header */,
    CellStyle = rightCellStyle;
});
```

---

Or in XAML...

Add XMLNS:

```
xmlns:sdk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
```

Add this resource:

```
<Style x:Key="RightCellStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
</Style>
```

Set on a column like this:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Binding}"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource RightCellStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to right align the `DataGridCell`, like this,

```
    <sdk:DataGrid Margin="104,82,139,71" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </sdk:DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the HorizontalContentAlignment.
If its in a style:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
```